# "System.NullReferenceException" Error While Using Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn ***one to many relations*** with EF Core.

In summary: I have two tables; Artists and Songs.

But when I try to reach songs which belongs that artist I am getting error.

Why I'm getting null reference error?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is in the value of `theArtist.Songs` ? Maybe you need to do `DB.Artists.Include(a => a.Songs)` to retrieve them from the db

Comment: Just curious, how are you getting that shading ?

Comment: @Bassie
The value of `theArtist.Songs` is null.
But it's not suppose to be null cuz in the database there is a song that belongs the artist.
But `Include` is solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: @TheGeneral
It's the dark theme of visual studio 22.
But I added a background pic with using ClaudiaIDE extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield most probably It would but my english is not enough to process that article.

Comment: In `Artist` change `public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }` to `public List<Song> Songs { get; set; } = new  List<Song> ();`

Comment: Next time, [please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the related entity you want in the list manually, include *Songs* like the following way:

```
var theArtist = DB.Artists.Include("Songs").FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID==1);
```